# How to determine when cmds in docker exec complete

Tags: maven, go, docker

I'm currently using the Docker Rest API to run an exec command on a container to start building a maven project. I was wondering if there was any way provided by Docker to determine when the cmds you attach to the exec cmd complete or if I need to start getting creative

Comment: By docker api, are you referring to the rest protocol, or just the `docker exec` cli?

Comment: @BMitch the rest protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [exec api spec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.25/#operation/ExecStart) if you do not set detach to true, the web socket should close once the command finishes. If you do detach from the the exec, then you can use the [exec inspect api](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.25/#operation/ExecInspect) and poll for Running to go to false.

If you're using the exec api to run an interactive shell and you run your commands as input to the shell without closing stdin, then that shell will hang just as if you ran it outside of docker. You can close stdin to the shell or you'll need to "get creative" if that's not an option.

Comment: So does Running refer to the status of the exec command as opposed to the state of the container?

Comment: For the exec inspect api, I believe so. Notice the Pid in the api reference is not 1 which it would be for the process running the container.